# How to change space between columns in horizontalBar in Chart.js?

Tags: angular, chart.js, bar-chart

This is my horizontalBar:
[image]

options:

```
option = {
    legend: {
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        beginAtZero: true,
        fontSize: 20,
        display: true,
        barThickness: 8,
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        fontSize: 20,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

and datasets:

```
this.ChartData = [
      { data: [this.worstRatingValues[0], 0], label: this.worstRatingKeys[0], borderWidth: 2 , borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)', backgroundColor: 'rgba(18, 151, 46,  0.6)', hoverBackgroundColor:  'rgba(18, 151, 46,  1)', hoverBorderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',  },
      { data: [0, this.worstRatingValues[1]], label: this.worstRatingKeys[1], borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)', backgroundColor: 'rgba(41, 201, 255, 0.6)', hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(41, 201, 255, 1)' ,hoverBorderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', },
      { data: [0, 0, this.worstRatingValues[2]], label: this.worstRatingKeys[2], borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 15, 235, 0.6)', hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 15, 235, 1)', hoverBorderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', },
      { data: [0, 0, 0, this.worstRatingValues[3]], label: this.worstRatingKeys[3], borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)', backgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 255, 15, 0.6)', hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 255, 15, 1)', hoverBorderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', },
      { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, this.worstRatingValues[4]], label: this.worstRatingKeys[4], borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)', backgroundColor: 'rgba(243, 255, 15, 0.6)', hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(243, 255, 15, 1)' , hoverBorderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',},
      { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, this.worstRatingValues[5]], label: this.worstRatingKeys[5], borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 128, 31, 0.6)', hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 128, 31,  1)' , hoverBorderColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',},

    ];
```

I know I can change the thickness of the column with the barThickness.
but the result is that:
[image]

so not all columns are visible.
How to reduce the space between the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` properties on the y-axis options. More info [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage).

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    beginAtZero: true,
    fontSize: 20,
    display: true,
    barThickness: 8,
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    barPercentage: 1
  }],
  ...
```

Values of 1 and 1 would remove all the space. Play around with it to achieve an optimum for your requirement.